# Calcular Puntaje Real de una tabla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Estoy teniendo problemas en sumar el puntaje de mi tabla,cuya informacion o puntaje se extrae de la base de datos.

Este es mi tabla donde el puntaje se va cargando al iniciar o cargar la pagina.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de la Tabla este esta en jsp con codigo Java.

Al aplicar la siguiente funcion en Javascript:

```html
<div class="table-responsive-vertical">
  <table
    class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-mc-light-blue"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Disciplina</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Genero</th>
        <th style="background-color: red">Equipo Rojo</th>
        <th style="background-color: yellow">Equipo Amarillo</th>
        <th style="background-color: turquoise">Puntaje Turqueza</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% 
        for (int i=0; i < v.size();i++){ puntaje p = (puntaje)v.elementAt(i);
      %>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Disciplina"><%=p.getNombredeporte()%></td>
        <td data-title="Categoria"><%=p.getCategoria() %></td>
        <td data-title="Genero"><%=p.getGenero() %></td>
        <td data-title="Puntaje"><%=p.getPuntaje1() %></td>
        <td data-title="Puntaje"><%=p.getPuntaje2() %></td>
        <td data-title="Puntaje"><%=p.getPuntaje3() %></td>
      </tr>
      <% } %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
function sumar() {
  var rojo = 0;
  var amarillo = 0;
  var turqueza = 0;
  elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i += 6) {
    rojo += +elementos[i + 3].textContent;
    amarillo += +elementos[i + 4].textContent;
    turqueza += +elementos[i + 5].textContent;
  }
  document.getElementById('projo').textContent = rojo;
  document.getElementById('pamarillo').textContent = amarillo;
  document.getElementById('pturqueza').textContent = turqueza;
}
sumar();
```

Y en la Pagina web se muestra en los siguientes Label lo cual estan identificados de la siguiente manera.

```
 <label>Puntaje Rojo :</label>
 <label id="projo" class="contador"></label>
 <label >Puntaje Amarillo :</label>
 <label id="pamarillo" class="contador"></label>
 <label>Puntaje Turqueza :</label>
 <label id="pturqueza" class="contador"></label>
```

Pero eh revisado la suma en la base de datos no me esta mostrando los valores correctos estos son los resultados que tengo en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual se nota la diferencia en Amarillo me esta restando 20 puntos y en turqueza me esta sumando 20 puntos.

Hasta el momento no llego a resolver este problema talvez sea la funcion que se esta aplicando mal.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código HTML de la tabla? La imagen no se ve demasiado bien y se ve las cantidades que se están sumando

Comment: estimado ya se coloco el codigo de la tabla que incluye cod java.

Comment: Hiciste la prueba con menos datos para ver donde se arma la desviacion?

Comment: te refieres que la tabla tenga menos datos?

Comment: Pon el código HTML completo que te genera el el programa con todos los datos, así podemos probar tu código con todos los datos

Comment: La función que suma los datos de la tabla parece correcta, quizá es la suma de superior la que está mal. Por cierto, el color es *Turque**s**a*

Comment: @Pablo Lozano podrias ayudarme o explicarme porque la suma que muestra la web no es igual que la que tengo en la base de datos , cuando dices suma de superior - a que te refieres gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Dices que la suma hecha por Javascript no da lo mismo que los números que se ven en la parte superior de la tabla. Lo que comento es que la suma de las filas parece correcta, así que me pregunto si la suma que se ve en la parte superior de la tabla será correcta.

Comment: @PabloLozano el resultado de la tabal en la web no es la misma, que la ultima imagen esa imagen eh o esa suma es de la base de datos  si te das cuenta el resultado es distinto.

Answer (score 0):

mira te pongo esta solucion: En tu body agrega diferentes clases a cada color, para pode indentificar cada td.

```
<tbody>
                <%
                for (int i=0; i < v.size();i++){
                    puntaje p = (puntaje)v.elementAt(i);

                %>
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="Disciplina"><%=p.getNombredeporte()%></td>
                    <td data-title="Categoria"><%=p.getCategoria() %></td>
                    <td data-title="Genero"><%=p.getGenero() %></td>
                    <td data-title="Puntaje" class='pRojo'><%=p.getPuntaje1() %></td>
                    <td data-title="Puntaje" class='pAmarillo'><%=p.getPuntaje2() %></td>
                    <td data-title="Puntaje" class='pAzul'><%=p.getPuntaje3() %></td>
                </tr>
               <%
               }
               %>
            </tbody>
```

Después con tu codigo JavaScript puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
function sumar() {
  var rojo = 0;
  var amarillo = 0;
  var turqueza = 0;
  var rojoE = document.getElementsByClassName('pRojo');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(rojoE,function(item){rojo+=item.value});
  var amarilloE = document.getElementsByClassName('pAmarillo');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(rojoE,function(item){amarillo+=item.value});
  var azulE = document.getElementsByClassName('pAzul');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(rojoE,function(item){turqueza+=item.value});

  document.getElementById('projo').textContent = rojo;
  document.getElementById('pamarillo').textContent = amarillo;
  document.getElementById('pturqueza').textContent = turqueza;
  }
```

Intenta esto, aqui lo que hacemos es recorrer todos los elementos que tengan esas clases, sin necesidad de ir contando celdas como lo estas haciendo tu. Este es un poco mas especifico, hay que tener cuidado, porque si no existe la clase, el document.getElementsByClassName va a tronar.